# Regex is not working in powershell code, returns nothing

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a problem with my regex, it is only selecting one error among four errors.

When I use this regex in my powershell code, it does not work. It is returning nothing.

My code is :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '/Users/user/Documents/tmp' -filter '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName 
    [regex]::Matches($content, "(ERROR\:[\S\s\n\r]*?\n)(C:)") | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Groups[0].Value -replace '\r?\n'
    }
}
```

My regex is:

https://regex101.com/r/kU9gR4/1

What is the problem in my regex and in my powershell code?

Comment: `Get-Content $_.FullName` -> `Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw`

Comment: Using Select-String would also work here. Either way the file needs to be a single string. Not a string array.